# How to setup Minio Console on a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minio, k3s

I have deployed Minio on a Kubernetes cluster of 3 nodes:

```
NAME           STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
raspberrypi2   Ready    <none>                 4h32m   v1.22.6+k3s1
antonis-dell   Ready    control-plane,master   4h36m   v1.22.6+k3s1
raspberrypi    Ready    <none>                 4h32m   v1.22.6+k3s1
```

The architecture is presented in the image below.

[image]

I have access to the Minio browser but I cannot figure out how I can setup the Minio console inside the cluster. In Minio Console official repo https://github.com/minio/console, some steps are presented.

For example step **1. Create a user console using mc**:

```
mc admin user add myminio/
Enter Access Key: console
Enter Secret Key: xxxxxxxx
```

**setp 2. Create a policy for console with admin access to all resources (for testing)**

```
cat > admin.json << EOF

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Action": [
                "admin:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ],
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

How I can create the user and the policy, if minio runs inside a container? How to access and where?

Comment: You need to create an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource to expose the MinIO service outside of the cluster.

Comment: Can you please provide some details regarding how to exploit ingress for the minio console?

Comment: did you tried `kubectl exec -it <pod name> -- /bin/bash` to go inside the container ? how ideally i think there should be some api to add user. you can port-forward and try accessing console of minio.